# Почему не работает position fixed и flexbox контейнер?

Tags: css, flexbox

У меня есть шапка сайта(header__top) с position fixed и justify-content: space-between, но justify-content не работает, и я знаю что при position fixed нужно задавать ширину блоку, но если я задаю width:100% то header улетает за границы экрана и границы container.

```
.container{
    max-width: 1504px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.header__top{
    position: fixed;
    

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between; 

    z-index: 111;
    transition: all .4s;
}
```

Comment: Ширину задавать не обязательно, если указать `left` и `right`...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать ширину в `vw`
Проценты считаются относительно ширины родителя, а vw - относительно ширины экрана устройства

```
.header__top{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw; 
    ...
}
```

P.S. А вообще было бы неплохо посмотреть на ваш HTML